# Check overlap of date ranges in MySQL

Tags: mysql, range, overlapping-matches

This table is used to store sessions (events):

```
CREATE TABLE session (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, start_date date
, end_date date
);

INSERT INTO session
  (start_date, end_date)
VALUES
  ("2010-01-01", "2010-01-10")
, ("2010-01-20", "2010-01-30")
, ("2010-02-01", "2010-02-15")
;
```

We don't want to have conflict between ranges.
Let's say we need to insert a new session from **2010-01-05** to **2010-01-25**.
We would like to know the conflicting session(s).

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM session
WHERE "2010-01-05" BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
   OR "2010-01-25" BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
   OR "2010-01-05" >= start_date AND "2010-01-25" <= end_date
;
```

Here is the result:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | start_date | end_date   |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 2010-01-01 | 2010-01-10 |
|  2 | 2010-01-20 | 2010-01-30 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Is there a better way to get that?

---

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f21cc/2)

Comment: Your third condition is wrong. It is supposed to be `"2010-01-05" <= start_date AND "2010-01-25" >= end_date`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28802972/632951 for visualization. Your current third condition will never evaluate, because the first (and second) condition already covers it.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

I had such a query with a calendar application I once wrote. I think I used something like this:

```
... WHERE new_start < existing_end
      AND new_end   > existing_start;
```

**UPDATE** This should definitely work ((ns, ne, es, ee) = (new_start, new_end, existing_start, existing_end)):

1. ns - ne - es - ee: doesn't overlap and doesn't match (because ne < es)
2. ns - es - ne - ee: overlaps and matches
3. es - ns - ee - ne: overlaps and matches
4. es - ee - ns - ne: doesn't overlap and doesn't match (because ns > ee)
5. es - ns - ne - ee: overlaps and matches
6. ns - es - ee - ne: overlaps and matches

---

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ab2c/5/0)

Comment: Works great!, but I think @Pierre de LESPINAY is looking for inclusive ranges in his query: WHERE new_start <= existing_end
       AND new_end   >= existing_start;

Comment: @OsvaldoM. If he really were, he would have complained about 2 years ago …

Comment: I an event end today and another starts today, do they overlap ? In my opinion, they will overlap. But the SQL query won't say it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a6fd/1/0

Comment: @soulmerge, Actually, he would have just added the `=` into his actual code instead of bothering to complain about it.

Answer (score 40):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE
existing_start BETWEEN $newStart AND $newEnd OR 
existing_end BETWEEN $newStart AND $newEnd OR
$newStart BETWEEN existing_start AND existing_end

if (!empty($result))
throw new Exception('We have overlapping')
```

These 3 lines of sql clauses cover the 4 cases of overlapping required.

Comment: Even if the OP was not apparently looking for this overlapping definition, this answer is the best solution for the problem described by the question name. I was looking for this overlap, which is the true overlap.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "true overlap" but the top answer by @soulmerge is equivalent to this answer by Lamy. I was able to use the Z3 Theorem Solver to prove equivalence: http://www.grantjenks.com/projects/equivalent-inequalities/

Answer (score 22):

Lamy's answer is good, but you can optimize it a little more.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE
existing_start BETWEEN $newSTart AND $newEnd OR
$newStart BETWEEN existing_start AND existing_end
```

This will catch all four scenarios where the ranges overlap and exclude the two where they don't.

Comment: Are there other solutions besides this and the other two above?

Answer (score 4):

I had faced the similar problem. My problem was to stop booking between a range of blocked dates. For example booking is blocked for a property between 2nd may to 7th may. I needed to find any kind of overlapping date to detect and stop the booking. My solution is similar to LordJavac.

```
SELECT * FROM ib_master_blocked_dates WHERE venue_id=$venue_id AND 
(
    (mbd_from_date BETWEEN '$from_date' AND '$to_date') 
    OR
    (mbd_to_date BETWEEN  '$from_date' AND '$to_date')
    OR
    ('$from_date' BETWEEN mbd_from_date AND mbd_to_date)
    OR      
    ('$to_date' BETWEEN mbd_from_date AND mbd_to_date)      
)
*mbd=master_blocked_dates
```

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Given two intervals like (s1, e1) and (s2, e2) with s1<e1 and s2<e2
You can calculate overlapping like this:

```
SELECT 
     s1, e1, s2, e2,
     ABS(e1-s1) as len1,
     ABS(e2-s2) as len2,
     GREATEST(LEAST(e1, e2) - GREATEST(s1, s2), 0)>0 as overlaps,
     GREATEST(LEAST(e1, e2) - GREATEST(s1, s2), 0) as overlap_length
FROM test_intervals
```

Will also work if one interval is within the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can cover all date overlapping cases even when to-date in database can possibly be null as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` t
WHERE t.`startDate` <= $toDate
AND (t.`endDate` IS NULL OR t.`endDate` >= $startDate);
```

This will return all records that overlaps with the new start/end dates in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Mackraken's answer above is better from a performance perspective as it doesn't require several OR's in order to evaluate if two dates overlap. Nice solution!

However I found that in MySQL you need to use DATEDIFF instead of the minus operator -

```
SELECT o.orderStart, o.orderEnd, s.startDate, s.endDate
, GREATEST(LEAST(orderEnd, endDate) - GREATEST(orderStart, startDate), 0)>0 as overlaps
, DATEDIFF(LEAST(orderEnd, endDate), GREATEST(orderStart, startDate)) as overlap_length
FROM orders o
JOIN dates s USING (customerId)
WHERE 1
AND DATEDIFF(LEAST(orderEnd, endDate),GREATEST(orderStart, startDate)) > 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Recently I was struggling to perform operations with date. The following SQL query solved the issue to filter rows with multiple criteria related to date:

```
SELECT * FROM duty_register WHERE employee = '2' AND (
(
duty_start_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
OR
duty_end_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
)
OR
(
start_date BETWEEN duty_start_date AND duty_end_date
OR
end_date BETWEEN duty_start_date AND duty_end_date)
);
```

PS: This helped me find the entries with overlapping date ranges however may not be a good approach as it may be memory consuming.