# MySQL time overlapping

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a database to manage my schedule
the database looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE activities(
name VARCHAR(255),
startTime INT(11),
endTime INT(11)
);
```

Now I'd like to detect overlaps in activities.
so lets say i have the following variables:

```
$start=time();
$end=time()+3600;
```

now i want to query the database to get ALL activities that overlap with these times.
Anyone has an idea how to do this?

Thank you!

p.s. I realize similiar questions have already been asked but i couldn't find the answer for MySQL with a table similiar to this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL range date overlap check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545947/mysql-range-date-overlap-check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like

```
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE
(.$start. BETWEEN startTime AND endTime) OR
(.$end. BETWEEN startTime AND endTime) OR
(startTime < .$start. AND endTime > .$end.);
```

Comment: The solution I propose does the same thing with only two comparisons.

Comment: You don't think so? Why not? My query does the same if $end > $start which I think is quite safe to assume.

Comment: @Alfwed, your query won't return result if `$start` equals to ``endTime`` or `$end` equals to ``startTime``, will it? `n between min and max` is the same as `n >= min and n <= max` rather than `n > min and n < max`.

Comment: I could argue that a class scheduled between 3pm and 4pm does NOT overlap a class scheduled between 4pm and 5pm. It depends what the OP meant by overlap i think.

Comment: Anyway, the query proposed by Yahia is still doable with only 2 comparisons.

Comment: @Alfwed, I didn't say that your solution does not work. I just said that that your query does NOT return the same results as Yahia's query, although you wrote that it does.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd want something like:

```
mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `activities` WHERE `startTime`<".$start." AND `endTime`>".$end);
```

Just be careful to properly index your tables, otherwise that's gonna be one heck of a slow query.

Comment: would work for some situations but it won't work if my new activity starts before an existing one and ends after an existing one.

Comment: no, you need to take into account activities where startTime between $start and $end *OR* endTime between $start and $end

Answer (score 0):

Use the query below.

```
"SELECT * 
FROM `activities` 
WHERE `endTime`>".$start." AND `startTime`<".$end
```

The solution become quite obvious when you draw your problem down.