# How to convert date to mysql date format

Tags: java, mysql, between

**Table1**

```
id         int        pk
searchdate datetime
amount     float
```

Data for Table1

```
id   searchdate   amount
1    2014-02-05    100
2    2014-02-02    245
3    2014-02-11    344
```

here i want `data between 2014-02-01 to 2014-02-10`, but what i want from `datetime picker` is `"01-02-2014" (dd-mm-yyyy format)`. please help me to create MySQL between query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stackoverflow question slove my problem .. [Link for Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603318/mysql-query-for-certain-date-range)

Query..

```
Select * from Table1 where searchdate >= '2014-02-01 00:00:00' and searchdate <= '2014-02-10 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use string conversions *at all*. Use a `PreparedStatement`, and the `setTimestamp` method.

```
// TODO: Cleanup etc
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(
    "select * from table1 where searchdate >= ? and searchdate < ?");
st.setTimestamp(1, startDateTimeInclusive); // java.sql.Timestamp values
st.setTimestamp(2, endDateTimeExclusive);
```

Unless your ultimate intention is a string, you should avoid string conversions.