# Retrieve records from table based on two datetime fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data in the table

```
from_date    to_date
2015-05-12    2015-10-20
2015-10-21    2016-02-02
2016-02-03    NULL
```

Where NULL value in to_date denotes that this record is valid until this time.

The records I want to retrieve is between '2015-10-30' and '2016-08-08'. How do I get the second and third rows based on my search criteria?

Comment: `2015-10-21` isn't between `2015-10-30` and `2016-08-08`.

Comment: 2015-10-30 is between 2015-10-21 and 2016-02-02

Comment: Probably you are confusing yourself @SumanBhandari

Comment: Then what about `2016-08-08`?

Comment: to_date - NULL mean, this record is valid until today. since 2015-10-30 lies between second row. and '2016-08-08' lies in the third row, I need to be able to retrieve both these rows. Am I clearing myself @AlokPatel ?

Comment: In that case you need to query the table for each date. (eg. for `2015-10-30` and `2016-08-08`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out what I was looking for.

```
select * from table where
end_date >= start_search && start_date <= end_search
```

More detailed answer in the link below. Answered by [pacerier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632951/pacerier)

[mysql-query-for-certain-date-range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603318/mysql-query-for-certain-date-range)

Answer (score 1):

I am confused why are you expecting the second row in the result set. Is it something loose range searching (either by from_date or by to_date)?

You can try something like that:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM your_table
WHERE from_date >= startDate
AND IF(to_date IS NULL, TRUE, to_date <= endDate);
```

**Note:** Here `startDate` and `endDate` are the dates in your given range.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM your_table
WHERE 
'2015-10-30' BETWEEN from_date AND COALESCE(to_date,CURDATE())
OR 
'2016-08-08' BETWEEN from_date AND COALESCE(to_date,CURDATE())
```

Comment: to_date - NULL means, this record is valid until today. since '2015-10-30' lies between second row. and '2016-08-08' lies between third row, I need to be able to retrieve both these rows

Comment: One of the weird date range searches I've ever seen. No problem. Just tell me ` '2015-10-30' and '2016-08-08'` here are two dates you want to search with them. Is it always fixed to two?