# mysql check date range in other date range

Tags: php, mysql, date, range

I have a row with a date range

```
title | fromDate | tillDate
------------------------------------
my event | 2014-03-12 | 2014-03-13

my event 2 | 2014-03-14 | 2014-03-17

my event 3 | 2014-03-01 | 2014-03-10

my event 4 | 2014-03-01 | 2014-03-09
```

Now I have a second pair of date range and I want to check if the event is in the date range .. for example

checkStartDate = 2014-03-10
checkEndStartDate = 2014-03-14

So in the range would be "my event" , "my event 2" and "my event 3" ...

At this moment I want to just try and get ALL the dates between my range (so between 2014-03-10 and 2014-03-14) and write one big query for it ... But there must be an easier way to do this right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL range date overlap check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545947/mysql-range-date-overlap-check)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT title FROM table WHERE (DATE('2014-03-10') BETWEEN DATE(fromDate) AND DATE(tillDate) OR DATE('2014-03-14') BETWEEN DATE(fromDate) AND DATE(tillDate) OR (DATE('2014-03-10') <= DATE(fromDate) AND DATE('2014-03-14') >= DATE(tillDate)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select title from table
where checkStartDate  <= fromDate 
and checkEndStartDate <= tillDate
```

I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
select *  from events_table  where fromDate >= checkStartDate   and tillDate <= checkEndStartDate
```