# How to validate a user's date inputs when the validation criteria is stored in an SQL database

Tags: php, sql, validation, date, range

i has the next table:

```
| ID | Date-Start |Date-End|
| 01 | 2014-04-10 |2014-04-12|
| 02 | 2014-04-13 |2014-04-15|
| 03 | 2014-04-16 |2014-04-18|
| 04 | 2014-04-19 |2014-04-22|
```

The user select 2 dates and i need to validate this 2 dates not cross with the ones in table.
For example user enter 2014-04-20 to 2014-04-21, this is invalid because in record 04 this range are occupied from 2014-04-19 to 2014-04-22. Ty for help. Excuse my bad english.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545947/mysql-range-date-overlap-check

Comment: Ty David, very helphulp :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE ((Date-Start >= '$first-date' AND Date-Start <= '$second-date')
 OR (Date-End >= '$first-date' AND Date-End <= '$second-date'))
```

If it returns a result then the given period should be invalid

Comment: Hi gbestard, ty for your response, but the select dont work for me because if i choose this dates: 2014-04-20 to 2014-04-21, the select dont take this range like occupied and dont return nothing, and this should be return the last record (| 04 | 2014-04-19 |2014-04-22|), ty

Comment: If it doesn't return anything then the given period is ok

Answer (score 0):

So you can do

```
(r1.dateEnd > r2.dateStart) and (r2.dateEnd > r1.dateStart)
```

to see if the rows overlap.  e.g. to find overlapping rows

```
select * from DateTable r1, DateTable r2 
where (r1.dateEnd > r2.dateStart) and (r2.dateEnd > r1.dateStart)
```

or to find the overlapping dates with a query:

```
select * from DateTable r1
where ( r1.dateEnd >= {start_date} ) and ( {end_date} >= r1.dateStart )
```

Comment: Hi Chrisky, excuse me but i are a little new in mysql, i dont understand how this work, what is r1 and r2?, and where i put the dates  provided for user, ty

Comment: Sorry, I could have been clearer. The example above spots overlapping entries in the one DateTabe - it's aliased to r1 and r2. I've edited the answer.  The crucial thing is to have a comparison like the one I've given - this covers all circumstances of overlapping, e.g. when one span completely contains another span.  If you use the other types of comparison outlined here, you'll not catch that case.

Answer (score 0):

Using pseudo code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `TABLE` WHERE `Date-Start` BETWEEN <start-date> AND <end-date> OR `Date-End` BETWEEN <start-date> AND <end-date>
```

Then you can check if count > 0. If it is, you know the dates are occupied.

Comment: Hi Samsquanch, ty for your response, but the select dont work for me because if i choose this dates: 2014-04-20 to 2014-04-21, the select dont take this range like occupied and return 0, and this should be return the last record (| 04 | 2014-04-19 |2014-04-22|), ty

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
 (( $fIni BETWEEN fechaIni AND fechaFin)
 OR ($fFin BETWEEN fechaIni AND fechaFin))
```

Comment: add certain explanation as well to your answer