# MySQL: NOT BETWEEN not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, date, between

I have a booking system and I have to check if a *date* **or** a *date range* is not in between of date ranges saved in MySQL.

Here is my table:

```
bookings(id, property_id, booked_from_date, booked_to_date)
```

Each property can have none, one or multiple dates booked.

My query to check if a certain date or range is not in between one of the booked periods is

```
SELECT p.id, p.title
FROM properties p 
LEFT JOIN bookings b ON p.id = b.property_id 
WHERE 
    COALESCE('selected_from_date' NOT BETWEEN p.booked_from_date AND b.booked_to_date , TRUE) AND 
    COALESCE('selected_to_date' NOT BETWEEN p.booked_from_date AND b.booked_to_date , TRUE)
GROUP BY main.id
```

My logic is that if a certain date is not in between a booked range then it is available but the query does not return the correct results.

Is there any way of excluding all properties that are available between those dates ?

Thank you

**EDIT**

Here is the table which holds the booked ranges

```
id boat_id booking_id booked_from_date booked_to_date
 5      22 NULL       2016-05-28       2016-06-04
 6      22 NULL       2016-07-02       2016-07-09
 7      22 NULL       2016-07-16       2016-07-23
 9      25 NULL       2016-06-04       2016-06-11
```

Here is the parent table

```
 id title
 21 Vacanza tra comfort e benessere su barca a vela ad...
 22 Vacanza in Barca a Vela su Gib Sea 372
 23 Vacanza da sogno su un Motor Yacht
 24 Capri & Costiera Amalfitana
 25 Golfo di Napoli in barca a vela
 26 Il 44 piedi che sorprende
```

What i expect:

- If I search for `2016-05-30` I expect to return all boats except `id 22`, because the date `2016-05-30` is between a range already booked.
- If I search from `2016-06-05` to `2016-06-10` I expect to return all boats except `id 25`

Hope this helps

Comment: You have period `selected_from_date - selected_to_date` and want to check if it intersects with any record in `bookings` table (where period is `booked_from_date - booked_to_date`)? And find rows in `properties` where selected period is not booked, right?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Andrew I want to find any results that are not booked on a selected date, or a selected date range. Similar to any booking system.

Comment: @Strawberry I will update my question shortly

Comment: What's the difference between `id` and `booking_id` ?!?

Comment: Search for date range intersection in a NOT EXISTS subquery.

Comment: @Strawberry That is a field that in this context is irrelevant.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Hi, could you provide some examples or articles ? Thank you

Comment: [mysql-range-date-overlap-check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545947/mysql-range-date-overlap-check)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will find all not booked items from `properties`. Main idea is to search booked items (and place condition for it in `JOIN bookings`). Then transform `JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE bookings.id IS NULL` - it will reverse condition from `booked` to `not booked`.

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.title
FROM properties p 
LEFT JOIN bookings b ON p.id = b.property_id
  AND b.booked_from_date <= 'selected_to_date'
  AND b.booked_to_date >= 'selected_from_date'
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

Comment: @C.Ovidiu Note that 'selected_to_date' and 'selected_from_date' might be the same day, and note how 'to' is paired with `from` and 'from' is paired with `to`.

Comment: With some tweaking I managed to make this work. My original query has a lot of other search parameters as well, so I wanted to ask if the performance impact is noticeable ? Never the less, I thank you very much for the help. @Strawberry It had me confused a bit, I then realized they were inverted

Comment: This will be not slower than any `BETWEEN` condition. You probably already has index on `bookings.property_id` (foreign key to some other table). And this query can use indexes on `booked_from_date` and `booked_to_date` (if you have really big data or just want to add it for optimization). So, all conditions can be resolved with index scan - this must be as fast as possible ;-)