# Selecting date range between or greater

Tags: mysql

**Data**

```
CREATE TABLE `employees_salaries` (
  `PK_salary` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `PK_worker` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `contract_start` date NOT NULL,
  `contract_end` date NOT NULL,
  `gross` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `insurence_cost1` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `insurence_cost2` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `to_payout` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `due` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `employees_salaries` (`PK_salary`, `PK_worker`, `contract_start`, `contract_end`, `gross`, `insurence_cost1`, `insurence_cost2`, `to_payout`, `due`) VALUES
(1, 4, '2017-10-01', '2017-10-31', '1000.00', '137.10', '171.60', '768.24', '1171.60'),
(2, 4, '2017-10-01', '2017-10-31', '2000.00', '274.20', '392.20', '1459.48', '2392.20'),
(3, 15, '2017-08-01', '2017-09-08', '2000.00', '274.20', '392.20', '1418.88', '2392.20'),
(4, 17, '2017-08-01', '2017-09-08', '2000.00', '274.20', '392.20', '1459.48', '2392.20'),
(5, 9, '2017-08-01', '2017-09-08', '2826.12', '303.39', '433.95', '2058.08', '3260.07'),
(6, 11, '2017-08-01', '2017-09-08', '2000.00', '274.20', '392.20', '1459.48', '2392.20'),
(7, 5, '2017-08-01', '2017-09-08', '2000.00', '274.20', '392.20', '1418.88', '2392.20'),
(8, 6, '2017-08-01', '2017-09-08', '2000.00', '274.20', '392.20', '1459.48', '2392.20');
```

**Query**

```
set @dstart = "2017-10-01",@dend = "2017-10-30";

select employees_salaries.PK_worker , coalesce(sum(employees_salaries.gross),0) as p_am, coalesce(sum(insurence_cost1 + insurence_cost2),0) as incost
        from   employees_salaries 
        /* This example won't return reliable data
        WHERE    employees_salaries.contract_start      >= @dstart
        and    employees_salaries.contract_end <= @dend
        */
     GROUP BY employees_salaries.PK_worker
```

I am trying to accomplish following result :

*Scenario*

- We set the time range for the query, show the salaries for `@dstart = "2017-10-01",@dend = "2017-10-30";`

Logically it should be **contract_start** should be between our *@dstart* *@dend*,

**contract_end** should be also between *@dstart* *@dend*, but what if **contract_end** is for example 2017-12-30? It will produce such logic

is 2017-12-30 between 2017-10-01 and 2017-10-30? Answer is no, because its greater.

It possibly applies to **contract_start** as well : is 2017-09-01 is between 2017-10-01 and 2017-10-30? No, but the **contract_end** is in range of thous.

The question is how to implement such scenario? any hints appreciated

**MCVE** : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wAQ2eGfp2kCAdQ7QUBRYKp/3

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. You mean both *mmonth* and *payout_date* should be in the date range?

Comment: I assume for the logic at least one should, but walk through the scenario it's not as simple as it looks, also cleaned up the logic a bit

Comment: Are you looking for a range overlap?

Comment: Not sure if its called so but if you say so

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: As the Query, but with the proper WHERE clause

Comment: Which rows are you expecting as a result?

Comment: I gave you the select employees_salaries.PK_worker , coalesce(sum(employees_salaries.gross),0) as p_am, coalesce(sum(insurence_cost1 + insurence_cost2),0) as incost :) just look on the query example

Comment: The question is how to implement the where clause described in the scenario

Comment: The problem is we do not understand the scenario. Give us examples to help us understand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545947/check-overlap-of-date-ranges-in-mysql

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yup thats it

Comment: Then it should be something like `WHERE employees_salaries.contract_start <= @dend and employees_salaries.contract_end >= @dstart`

Comment: Figured it out myself, answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set @dstart = "2017-10-01",@dend = "2017-10-30";

    select employees_salaries.PK_worker , coalesce(sum(employees_salaries.gross),0) as p_am, coalesce(sum(insurence_cost1 + insurence_cost2),0) as incost
            from   employees_salaries 

            WHERE
            @dstart BETWEEN employees_salaries.contract_start AND employees_salaries.contract_end 
   OR  @dend BETWEEN employees_salaries.contract_start AND employees_salaries.contract_end 
   OR @dstart >= employees_salaries.contract_start AND @dend <= employees_salaries.contract_end 


         GROUP BY employees_salaries.PK_worker
```