# MySQL: Validate for date range within rate range (laravel optional)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hey guys (and girlies)

Can someone point out to validate / search for a date range within a date range? I am using Laravel PHP but raw SQL will be perfect as well.

I want to validate if a date range exists, within a date range. Basically I want a solid validation to avoid overlapping date ranges.

Example (and the concept I have at the moment) (laravel syntax)

`->where('start_date','>=',$myrange_start)`
`->where('start_date','<=',$myrange_end)`

Which will validate for for a start date in the database between the date range

and

`->where('start_end','>=',$myrange_start)`
`->where('start_end','<=',$myrange_end)`

Which will validate for for an end date in the database between the date range

And which has also kind of worked for me is

`->whereRaw('? between start_date and end_date', [$today])`

however, what I want to achieve is to say something like

`->whereRaw('? between start_date and end_date', [$myrange_start, $myrange_end])`

so see if there are date ranges which

a) start: on start, between start and end, on end
b) start: on end
c) end: on start, between start and en, on end
d) start BEFORE start date and ends AFTER ends date
e) start AFTER start date and ends BEFORE end date

Is this possible?

Comment: Your first code is fine, if a date range is inside another one then both `start_date` and `end_date` of that range will be between `start_date` and `end_date` of the other one

Comment: @you can use whereBetween. You can check link  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

Answer (score 3):

This is the overlapping range problem, and to quote [this canonical SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545947/check-overlap-of-date-ranges-in-mysql), the `WHERE` clause should be something like:

```
WHERE new_start < existing_end
    AND new_end > existing_start;
```

Translating this to Laravel code:

```
->where('start_date', '<', $myrange_end)
->where('start_end', '>', $myrange_start)
```

This would return true if there *is* an overlap between the two ranges.  If instead you want to find out if there *isn't* an overlap, then we can try:

```
->where('start_date', '>=', $myrange_end)
->orWhere('start_end', '<=', $myrange_start)
```

Comment: Thanx for your help! So I think this should then do the job. (trying to post formatted styling in the comment dosnt seem to work

    `where(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
        $q->where('start_date', '>=', $start)
            ->where('start_date', '<=', $end);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
        $q->where('end_date', '>=', $start)
            ->where('end_date', '<=', $end);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
            $q->where('start_date', '<', $start)
                ->where('end_date', '>', $end);
        });`

Answer (score 1):

Laravel official docs [laravel docs whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)

```
ModelName::whereBetween('date_field', [ $start_Date, $end_date ])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, think this should then work. you guys can comment

```
        where(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
            $q->where('start_date', '>=', $start)
            ->where('start_date', '<=', $end);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
            $q->where('end_date', '>=', $start)
                ->where('end_date', '<=', $end);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
            $q->where('start_date', '<', $start)
                ->where('end_date', '>', $end);
        });
```