# How to find the number of employees in a calender year?

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically this question was asked in an interview and I couldn't answer.

The tables employee is as follows:

```
  id |  name | start_date | end_date

    1      A     2015-01-09   2018-03-23
    2      B     2012-07-21   2019-01-22
    3      C     2013-04-07    null
              -
          -
          -
```

Now I have to find the id,name of all employees who worked during the year 2017.

Can you please help me.

Comment: Did you have to provide code or just answer/explain?

Comment: This is a basic SQL query, what was it that you couldn't figure out?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy It's actually not so basic, if you don't know the overlapping range problem.  But yet, it would have been nice to see an attempt by the OP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I disagree, the range problem is a simple algorithmic problem. Even if you're unfamiliar with SQL in general you could even guess

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM employee
WHERE YEAR(start_date) <= 2017 AND (end_date IS NULL OR YEAR(end_date) >= 2017)
```

hope this query doesn't require explanation, because it's pretty clear)

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.  If the year of the start and end date were both in 2017, then that record should be a match, but your condition `YEAR(start_date) < 2017` would always rule out such a record.

Comment: This would exclude any employee who has joined in 2017.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen exactly!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah... ty! Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the overlapping range problem, which can be handled by this query:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM employees
WHERE
    ('2017-01-01' <= end_date OR end_date IS NULL) AND
    '2017-12-31' >= start_date;
```

Comment: Not sure why we would need to check for the `end_date` though.

Comment: @DarshanMehta Have a look at the comment under your answer.

Comment: Yep, corrected it now, and deleted as it became the copy of your answer :)

Comment: Looks correct but just curious as to the reasoning behind having the criteria before the field names? i.e. why '2017-01-01' <= end_date     as opposed to    end_date >= '2017-01-01'     . Both are the same but it just looks strange, wondering if there is a reason for it?

Comment: @ChrisCarroll I based my answer off [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545947/check-overlap-of-date-ranges-in-mysql) and did not bother to rearrange things.  You may do that if you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's fine, as I said I knew it wasn't any different but I just found it strange to look at, was afraid I was missing something. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do,

```
select * from employee where start_date >= '2017-01-01' and end_date <= '2017-12-31'
```