# codeigniter select records from date range without repeating a record

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter-3

Im working on a project that needs the following query but i couldn't get it done.

DATABASE: `evenstdb`

```
--------------------------------------
| Event_id | startDate |    endDate  |
--------------------------------------
|82637     |01-02-2020 |  02-03-2020 |
--------------------------------------
|66363     |10-03-2020 |  31-11-2020 |
--------------------------------------
```

i have a page that i should list the event according to the selected date range. everything works fine but the problem is that sometimes i get the same event listed twice because I'm listing the events according to the `startDate` and the `endDate` at the same time. sometimes the start and the end date are in the selected date range. How can i display an event only once?

my code:

```
// $date1 and $date2 are date inputs from the form 

$query = $this->db->where('startDate >=', $date1);
$query = $this->db->where('startDate <=', $date2);
$query = $this->db->get('evenstdb');
$results1 =  $query->result();

$query = $this->db->where('endDate >=', $date1);
$query = $this->db->where('endDate <=', $date2);
$query = $this->db->get('evenstdb');
$results2 =  $query->result();

$data["eventsList"] = array_merge($results1,$results2);
```

Comment: Why don't you write this 4 date conditions in one query?

Comment: i'm not sure about the syntax cause im very new to codeigniter can you show me how pleae?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each record should match two date ranges simultaneously, you can try to get needed records via one query with all 4 conditions:

```
$this->db->where('startDate >=', $date1)
         ->where('startDate <=', $date2)
         ->where('endDate >=', $date1)
         ->where('endDate <=', $date2);

$result = $this->db->get('evenstdb')->result();
```

If each record should match at least one date range, you can also try to get needed records via one query but group conditions into two parts connected with `OR` (record will be returned if any of these two groups returns `true`):

```
$this->db->group_start()
             ->where('startDate >=', $date1)
             ->where('startDate <=', $date2)
                 ->or_group_start()
                     ->where('endDate >=', $date1)
                     ->where('endDate <=', $date2)
                 ->group_end()
         ->group_end();

$result = $this->db->get('evenstdb')->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed a query to find overlapping date ranges in MySQL.  This solution performs much better than the date range solution above, and works perfectly.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62761904/11822079

You can do similarly:

```
AND DATEDIFF(LEAST($date2, endDate),GREATEST($date1, startDate)) > 0;
```

Example query for the link:

```
SELECT o.orderStart, o.orderEnd, s.startDate, s.endDate
, GREATEST(LEAST(orderEnd, endDate) - GREATEST(orderStart, startDate), 0)>0 as overlaps
, DATEDIFF(LEAST(orderEnd, endDate), GREATEST(orderStart, startDate)) as overlap_length
FROM orders o
JOIN dates s USING (customerId)
WHERE 1
AND DATEDIFF(LEAST(orderEnd, endDate),GREATEST(orderStart, startDate)) > 0;
```