# OR clauses drastically slowing down MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a query that is slowed down because of the following 3 OR clauses:

```
select * from book join library_member USING(book_id)
where member_id = 1145
and
( Date_add(Current_date(), interval 1 month) BETWEEN 
                 book.check_in AND book.check_out ) 
          OR ( Current_date() BETWEEN book.check_in AND 
             book.check_out ) 
          OR ( book.check_out BETWEEN Current_date() AND Date_add( 
                                              Current_date(), 
                                              interval 1 month) 
             ) 
          OR ( book.check_in BETWEEN 
               Current_date() AND Date_add(Current_date(), interval 1 month) )
```

Is there a better way of querying for either of these 4 scenarios?

Comment: Please prepend each column with the table name or alias where it belongs to. It's not obvious to us which tables have which columns.

Comment: Hard to believe. How many books does member 1145 have checked out? Are you sure you have the correct conditions? How can a book checkout or checkin be a month in the future? What are the table definitions? What indexes do you have? What does EXPLAIN say about the execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT c.olumns
     , y.ou
     , a.ctually
     , n.eed
  FROM book b
  JOIN library_member m
    ON m.book_id = b.book_id
 WHERE m.member_id = 1145
   AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) > b.check_in
   AND CURRENT_DATE() < b.check_out
```

Indexes on (b.check_in,b.check_out) and (m.book_id) would be useful

Comment: This gives a different result from the query I had originally :(

Comment: It can only be a case of rearranging the `less thans` and `greater thans` - or possibly using an exclusion join. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This solution won’t work.  Here the scenario that it is missing.  
Dates 1
Jan 2020
Jun 2020

Dates 2
Jan 2019
Jun 2021

It doesn’t handle this scenario as this will return false:
AND Jun 2021 > Jan 2020
   AND Jan 2019 < Jun 2020

Answer (score -1):

Yes - there is a faster way to find overlaps of dates!  I recently had a requirement like this and I was delighted to find a solution on stack overflow that doesn't use OR.

I tested this out in my code and it works flawlessly and performs really fast.

You can check for overlaps of dates like this:

```
AND DATEDIFF(LEAST(Date_add(Current_date(), interval 1 month), book.check_out),GREATEST(Current_date(), book.check_in)) > 0;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62761904/11822079

Comment: That is correct that functions do not use indexes.  However, based on a lot of experience with this, this solution works much faster since it's a single WHERE clause instead of 4.   You do need to add additional clauses based on other fields.  In the query in the question, there should be an index on member_id

Comment: two where conditions without an OR would be faster.  You are correct on that.  However, your answer to this question wont work as it's missing a scenario.   That's why I love this solution of one clause for the overlap dates.  It works much more efficiently than the ORs, and it gives the same result.

Comment: The test for overlaps is when event A starts before event B ends, and ends after Event B starts. There's no other test.

Comment: I see that you are insistent that you are correct.  Here is the scenario that you are mssing.  I dont appreciate the down vote.

Dates 1
Jan 2020
Jun 2020

Dates 2
Jan 2019
Jun 2021

Your solution doesn’t handle this scenario as this will return false:
AND Jun 2021 > Jan 2020
   AND Jan 2019 < Jun 2020

Comment: I dont have anything to fix.  The solution provided above works flawlessly.  I tested it out recently for my own project.  I have years of experience using the OR solution, and how it slows down the MySQL query.  Please attempt to fix your answer to include the scenario I gave you and you'll see what I mean...

Comment: Agreed.  It's faster than multiple OR clauses.  So why the downvote if you aren't familiar with it?

Comment: No. It isn't. That's my point. As discussed; it cannot use an index.

Comment: I didn't say it will use an index.  I said it's faster than multiple OR clauses.  "That is correct that functions do not use indexes. However, based on a lot of experience with this, this solution works much faster since it's a single WHERE clause instead of 4".  Please remove the down vote, as this answer should improve the performance, and it works!